# React-native running app error while gradle

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and i went trough making my first app, and all good until i got to run it because i get this error, i would ¡be thankful if someone could help me, i did all the tutorial that react-native provide in it's page so i think i installed it correctly.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at makeError (/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide a more detailed console output, so we can actually help you?

Comment: ok ill edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

As the logs mention, it cannot compile you app since the location of your android SDK cannot be found.

```
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/fovu/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.
```

It seems that your properties file points to a wrong SDK directory, your **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** path points to a wrong directory or the **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** path doesn't exist at all.

I'd recommend you to read through the official setup documentation and following each step: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

**Appendix**

I have seen in your logs that react-native doesn't even see an emulator, hence this line:

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
```

So you need to either manually launch an emulator or if you don't have an android emulator, install one. Or if you want: You can try to install the app on your phone by plugging it into your computer and enable USB debugging on your phone.

Cheers.